# Component can't find variable in .scss file

Tags: angular

*Angular.json* snippet:

```
"root": "",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "prefix": "ra",
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "aot": false,
        "assets": [
          "src/assets",
          "src/favicon.ico",
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
          "includePaths": ["assets/scss"]
        },
      }
```

New to Angular and I think I have an easy problem but just don't understand the inner workings of how *scss* is compiled. I'm importing some *scss* in my root *styles.scss* component. Here's what's in the *styles.scss*:

```
@import './assets/scss/global';
```

Here's what's in the *_global.scss*:

```
@import './variables';
```

And here's the contents of that file:

```
$spacer-4: 0.25em; //4px
$spacer-6: 0.375em; //6px
$spacer-8: 0.5em; //8px
$spacer-10: 0.625em; //10px
$spacer-12: 0.75em; //12px
$spacer-16: 1em; //16px
$spacer-20: 1.25em; //20px
$spacer-24: 1.5em; //24px
$spacer-30: 1.875em; //30px
$spacer-32: 2em; //32px
$spacer-36: 2.25em; //36px
```

The problem is within a component's scss file that references one of the variables. The error is thrown from the component:

```
ERROR in ./src/navigation/app-navigation/app-navigation.component.scss    

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

margin-top: $spacer-10;
           ^
  Undefined variable.
```

If I'm not getting a compile time error that the file isn't found then I shouldn't be seeing this error, right?

Here's the file structure of the app:

```
-- src
    -- app
        -- navigation
            --app-navigation
                -- app-navigation.component.scss
    -- assets
        -- scss
            -- _global.scss
            -- _variables.scss
    -- styles.scss
```

Comment: Can you show the relative file structure of the relevant files

Comment: I updated the post with the structure. I am hoping that I don't have to import this file into each angular component that uses it.

Comment: You will, unless you would rather use the [CSS Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) approach which is great unless you maybe need to support IE etc. However keep in mind, the import suggestion acts kind of like a namespace so it's really not that tough to add `@import 'blah';` to a component file when you actually need it and cuts down on compile times by only including refs when/where needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the order of inception. Your default styles.scss is the last in line in the order so your component doesn't have a reference to your variables/globals when it's inferred.

To fix it you just add an import reference to the component itself so it can receive those vars when it's needed. Which makes a good case for applying some presentation layer architecture rules to your uses. Such as with variables, I would suggest keeping it a file with ONLY vars since they will not transpile and then you can reference it where those vars are needed and not have any duplicated CSS as you would if you had any actual CSS in the globals file in the compiled assets.

I suggest if you haven't already add the `stylePreprocessorOptions` to your build configuration in angular.json with a fixed ref path to your directory that holds files like global so you don't have to make absolute paths each time you use it (don't forget to also add the declaration to your "serve" configuration in angular.json) like;

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
   "includePaths": [
      "assets/sass/"
    ]
},
```

Then in say your component scss file you only add `@import 'variables'` and it will provide the var values as necessary. Alternatively you could do the whole path but that can make maintenance a pain but will work just make sure your path is correct `@import '../../variables';` and with that in your component scss it will provide the vars also but I strongly recommend [setting up the import paths](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-shortcut-to-importing-styles-files-in-components) in angular.json.

Hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: Hi - thank you very much for clearing that up for me - I get it now. However, I still get "Can't find stylesheet to import". I've included the snippet from my angular.json above. Besides that path "assets/scss" I've also tried "src/assets/scss". But neither works.

Comment: @fumeng add the trailing `/` to your file path so it knows to look in that dirs children files instead of treating `scss` as a declarative path. Eg `"src/assets/scss/"`

Comment: Oh and just a side note, you might consider `rem` instead of `em` for your units of measurement to keep consistency for the scenario I see on your example. Since `em` will be relative to the font-size of nearest parent, not the document like `rem`, it can lead to maintenance headaches later down the road when trying to keep consistency...speaking from experience. Cheers!